# Celery and SQLAlchemy - This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, celery

I have a celery project connected to a MySQL databases. One of the tables is defined like this:

```
class MyQueues(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'accepted_queues'

    id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    customer = sa.Column(sa.String(length=50), nullable=False)
    accepted = sa.Column(sa.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
    denied = sa.Column(sa.Boolean, default=True, nullable=False)
```

Also, in the settings I have

```
THREADS = 4
```

And I am stuck in a function in `code.py`:

```
def load_accepted_queues(session, mode=None):

    #make query  
    pool = session.query(MyQueues.customer, MyQueues.accepted, MyQueues.denied)

    #filter conditions    
    if (mode == 'XXX'):
        pool = pool.filter_by(accepted=1)
    elif (mode == 'YYY'):
        pool = pool.filter_by(denied=1)
    elif (mode is None):
        pool = pool.filter(\
            sa.or_(MyQueues.accepted == 1, MyQueues.denied == 1)
            )

   #generate a dictionary with data
   for i in pool: #<---------- line 90 in the error
        l.update({i.customer: {'customer': i.customer, 'accepted': i.accepted, 'denied': i.denied}})
```

When running this I get an error:

```
[20130626 115343] Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/me/code/processing/helpers.py", line 129, in wrapper
    ret_value = func(session, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/me/code/processing/test.py", line 90, in load_accepted_queues
    for i in pool: #generate a dictionary with data
  File "/home/me/envs/me/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py", line 2341, in instances
    fetch = cursor.fetchall()
  File "/home/me/envs/me/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3205, in fetchall
    l = self.process_rows(self._fetchall_impl())
  File "/home/me/envs/me/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3174, in _fetchall_impl
    self._non_result()
  File "/home/me/envs/me/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3179, in _non_result
    "This result object does not return rows. "
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically
```

So mainly it is the part

```
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically
```

and sometimes also this error:

> DBAPIError: (Error) (, AssertionError('Result length not requested
>   length:\nExpected=1.  Actual=0.  Position: 21.  Data Length: 21',))
>   'SELECT accepted_queues.customer AS accepted_queues_customer,
>   accepted_queues.accepted AS accepted_queues_accepted,
>   accepted_queues.denied AS accepted_queues_denied \nFROM
>   accepted_queues \nWHERE accepted_queues.accepted = %s OR
>   accepted_queues.denied = %s' (1, 1)

I cannot reproduce the errror properly as it normally happens when processing a lot of data. I tried to change `THREADS = 4` to `1` and errors disappeared. Anyway, it is not a solution as I need the number of threads to be kept on `4`.

Also, I am confused about the need to use

```
for i in pool: #<---------- line 90 in the error
```

or

```
for i in pool.all(): #<---------- line 90 in the error
```

and could not find a proper explanation of it.

All together: any advise to skip these difficulties?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> All together: any advise to skip these difficulties?

yes. you absolutely *cannot* use a Session (or any objects which are associated with that Session), or a Connection, in more than one thread simultaneously, especially with MySQL-Python whose DBAPI connections are very thread-unsafe*.   You must organize your application such that each thread deals with it's own, dedicated MySQL-Python connection (and therefore SQLAlchemy Connection/ Session / objects associated with that Session) with no leakage to any other thread.

- Edit: alternatively, you can make use of mutexes to limit access to the Session/Connection/DBAPI connection to just one of those threads at a time, though this is less common because the high degree of locking needed tends to defeat the purpose of using multiple threads in the first place.

Comment: Uhms, so it is a problem with threads and concurrency... This is opening a wide range of possibilities I am not sure I know how to handle. Is there any specific way to head to work with one thread simultaneously? How can I trace which thread is doing what? Any hint will be highly appreciated!

Comment: If you're going to use threads, then you need to gain some mastery of one or both of two basic techniques - getting each thread to share no state at all, or using mutexes/locks around shared, non-thread-safe resources so that only one thread at a time touches it.   With SQLAclhemy, the "don't share anything" use case is commonly addressed using the [scoped_session](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html?highlight=scoped_session#unitofwork-contextual) construct.   But it's very useful if you have a firm grasp on what a "thread local variable" is and what that means.

Comment: Great. I have to improve the code I have been given, so to follow your valuable advises I really need more knowledge on threads and sessions. I have been looking for a comprehensive and from-zero level documentation and found http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_8/orm/session.html . As you know this topic more than anyone, could you suggest any other possible starting point? Thanks a lot, @zzzeek!

Comment: By the way (sorry), what is better, to use `pool.all()` or `pool` to create a dictionary from the results of the query? (last part of my original question)

Comment: dictionary from a query is best like this:  dict(session.query(Foo.x, Foo))

Comment: @zzzeek I have met the same issue with flask-sqlalchemy cooperating with flask-rq. which raised the exception as `ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.` in RQ Worker. I just followed the flask-rq example by using `with app.context() ` to share with session for the worker call async task with the Models. I wonder if any good suggestions exists for the cases?

Comment: this is a big subject area, and while I can't comment on how to set up flask or celery, I've tried to summarize the current known scenarios for this here: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#commands-out-of-sync-you-can-t-run-this-command-now-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-closed-automatically

Comment: @zzzeek Great, I'm so appreciated for the summary. It could got me clearly known my issue. While I wonder whether you could provide a human-easy interface for us to handle this issue . with more and more `multi-processes ` usecases like that. It would be more helpful on using sqlalchemy.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error while making a query to `SQL-Server` procedure using `SQLAlchemy`.
In my case, **adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` to the stored procedure** fixed the problem.

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE your_procedure_name
AS
BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for your procedure here
    SELECT *
    FROM your_table_name;

END;
```

Check out [this article](https://www.sqlshack.com/set-nocount-on-statement-usage-and-performance-benefits-in-sql-server/) for more details

Comment: In addition to the NOCOUNT ON; I had to add SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF, as well as my stored procedure produced warnings: "Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation". This occurred on SQL Server.

Answer (score 1):

I was using an `INSERT` statment. Adding

```
RETURNING id
```

at the end of the query worked for me. As per [this issue](https://github.com/sqlalchemy/sqlalchemy/issues/5433)

That being said it's a pretty weird solution, maybe something fixed in later versions of SQLAlchemy, I am using 1.4.39.

Answer (score 0):

**This error occurred for me when I used a `variable` in Python

and parsed it with an `UPDATE`
statement using pandas `pd.read_sql()`**

**Solution:**

I simply used `mycursor.execute()` instead of `pd.read_sql()`

`import mysql.connector` and `from sqlalchemy import create_engine`

**Before:**

```
pd.read_sql("UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE column = '%s'" % variable, dbConnection)
```

**After:**

```
mycursor.execute("UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE column = '%s'" % variable)
```

**Full code:**

```
import mysql.connector
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd


# Database Connection Setup >
sqlEngine = create_engine('mysql+pymysql://root:root@localhost/db name')
dbConnection = sqlEngine.connect()

db = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="root",
    database="db name")

mycursor = db.cursor()

variable = "Alex"
mycursor.execute("UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE column = '%s'" % variable)
```

Answer (score 0):

For me I got this error when I forgot to write the table calss name for the `select` function `query = select().where(Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)` so I had only to fix this by adding the class table name I want to get entries from like so:

```py
query = select(Assessment).where(
        Assessment.created_by == assessment.created_by)
```