# PyMySQL AssertionError: Result length not requested length

Tags: python, mysql, database-connection, connection-pooling, pymysql

I have a Python 3.4 application in beta that I am testing that uses PyMySQL 0.6.3 to connect to MySQL.  I have been getting occassional errors, AssertionError: Result length not requested length.  It is a multi-threaded application and this post [Celery and SQLAlchemy - This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317344/celery-and-sqlalchemy-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-clo) suggests that it may be due to threads sharing connections, which is probably happening.  How can I solve this?  PyMySQL doesn't provide a Connection Pool as is suggested in the post.