# UPDATE DB column - Python ResourceClosedError

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, sql-update

I am trying to update a column in Postgres table (Table1) using following python code

```
for i in range(0,len(df)):
        QUERY=""" UPDATE "Table1" SET "var"='%s' WHERE "Table"."id"='%s' """
         % (df['sum'][i], df['id'][i])
        pd.read_sql_query(QUERY,con=engine)
```

It is throwing the following error message.

```
ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been  closed automatically.
```

Could you please let me know how to solve this?

Comment: what `pd.read_sql_query` means? Is it a library call? Which library?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Celery and SQLAlchemy - This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17317344/celery-and-sqlalchemy-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-clo)

Comment: pd.read_sql_query Returns a DataFrame corresponding to the result set of the query string

Comment: Is there any other method to UPDATE Postgres table using python code? I need to do this for more than one million columns for different dates (I loop the dataframe data here)?

Comment: Well, an `UPDATE` query does not return any results. You can simply do `engine.execute(QUERY)` instead. You may also need to commit afterwards.