# Using Sqlalchemy on twisted servers to report errors at regular intervals

Tags: python-2.7, sqlalchemy, twisted

My twisted server, which connects four clients, initializes the Sqlalchemy engine once for each client. When the system runs for a period of time, the following error will be reported:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <class'sqlalchemy. exc. ResourceClosedError'>: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

/usr/lib/python 2.7/threading.py:801:u bootstrap_inner

3/usr/lib/python 2.7/threading.py:754:run

4/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_threadworker.py:46:work

5/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/_threads/_team.py:190:doWork

6 - < exception caught here >

7/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py:250:inContext

8/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/threadpool.py:266: <lambda>

9/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py:122:call WithContext

10/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/twisted/python/context.py:85:call WithContext

11. / data_server.py:231: check_update_mysqldb

12. / DRV / mysqldb_driver. py: 61: search_device_by_mac

13/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2895:first:

14/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:2687:u getitem_u

15/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:98:instances

16/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py:265:raise_from_cause

17/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:61:instances

18/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/query.py:3842:row_processor

19/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/loading.py:361:_instance_processor

20/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py:654:_getter

21/home/sites/data_collecting_server/venv/local/lib/python 2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/result.py:1088:_non_result

22]
```

Comment: Have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17348307/6560549)? The sqlalchemy author explains that the exact issue you are having is related to sharing resources across threads. Are you sure you aren't? Also check out [this]( https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/faq/connections.html#commands-out-of-sync-you-can-t-run-this-command-now-this-result-object-does-not-return-rows-it-has-been-closed-automatically), a section in the docs that addresses your specific issue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I've already seen two points you mentioned. So I just used the scoped_session mechanism. My current practice is that whenever there is a client connection, I initialize an Sqlalchemy connection and engine, and then call set_session() at the beginning of each thread function of the current connection to generate a separate session for operation. At the end of the thread function, I call close_session() to remove the session. All threads corresponding to the current client share connections and engines, but sessions are independent.

Comment: I don't know why I did this, but I still received the error above. What's wrong with my practice?

Comment: But doesn’t this: ‘All threads corresponding to the current client share connections and engines,’ violate the advice given by Mike Bayer in the answer I linked to above?

Comment: Sorry, maybe it's a problem I described. Threads share engines, session connections use scoped_session, and each thread has a separate session connection.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've solved this problem. Creating a new scoped_session for each thread really solves this problem. I used to call it incorrectly in my code and mixed session.

Comment: That's good to hear!

Comment: It is encouraged to answer your own question. You should move your edit into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem successfully. I wrote a test script that calls this way to isolate sessions

Here is my test code:

```
# coding=utf-8
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy import or_

from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.pool import NullPool

from config.settings import MYSQLDB_SETTING

import threading
import multiprocessing
import time


class SqlalchemyDriver(object):

    def __init__(self, host, user, password, port, database):
        db = "mysql+mysqldb://{user}:{password}@{host}:{port}/{database}?"\
            "charset=utf8".format(
                user=user,
                password=password,
                host=host,
                port=port,
                database=database
            )
        # self.engine = create_engine(db, poolclass=NullPool)
        self.engine = create_engine(db, pool_pre_ping=True, pool_size=10, max_overflow=10, pool_timeout=30)
        self.Session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=self.engine, autoflush=False))


drv = SqlalchemyDriver(
    host=MYSQLDB_SETTING["host"],
    user=MYSQLDB_SETTING["user"],
    password=MYSQLDB_SETTING["password"],
    port=MYSQLDB_SETTING["port"],
    database=MYSQLDB_SETTING["database"]
    )


class MysqldbDriver(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.classes = self.get_table_classes()
        self.session = drv.Session()
        print(id(self.session))

    def close_session(self):
        drv.Session.remove()

    def get_table_classes(self):
        base = automap_base()
        base.prepare(drv.engine, reflect=True)
        return base.classes

    def search_device_by_mac(self, mac_address):
        time.sleep(1)
        res = self.session.query(self.classes.client_management_device). \
                            filter_by(mac_address=mac_address).first()
        print(res)
        return res


def query_func():
    mysql = MysqldbDriver()
    mysql.search_device_by_mac('xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx')


def my_test():
    while True:
        t1 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)
        t2 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)
        t3 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)
        t4 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)
        t5 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)
        t6 = threading.Thread(target=query_func)

        t1.start()
        t2.start()
        t3.start()
        t4.start()
        t5.start()
        t6.start()
        time.sleep(3)
        t1.join()
        t2.join()
        t3.join()
        t4.join()
        t5.join()
        t6.join()
        time.sleep(1)


p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_test)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_test)
p3 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_test)
p4 = multiprocessing.Process(target=my_test)
print('running')
p1.start()
p2.start()
p3.start()
p4.start()
time.sleep(1)
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
p4.join()
time.sleep(1)
```